# CouchDB count all documents and return a number?

Tags: node.js, database, express, couchdb

We have a college project in CouchDB and I'm using node, I want to create a view that returns a number of all my documents by email.

I cannot find anything that works and I'm not sure what I'm missing, I tried a lot of different reduce functions and emit methods.

Thanks for any answers.

The documents have 2 fields, name and email

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting images as doing so is exclusionary to those with vision impairments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the [db endpoint](http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/docs/api/database/common.html#get--db) because the response field `doc_count` includes design documents along with other documents that may not have an `email` field.

A straight forward way to do this is with a view. The code snippet demonstrates the difference between db info `doc_count` and a view's `total_rows` using [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/).  I'd guess there's probably more interesting uses for the index.

The design doc is trivial

```js
{
 _id: '_design/my_index',
   views: {
     email: {
       map: function(doc) {
         if (doc.email) emit(doc.email);
       }.toString()
    }
  }
}
```

And the view query is very efficient and simple.

```js
db.query('my_index/email', {
        include_docs: false,      
        limit: 0
      })
```

```js
const gel = id => document.getElementById(id);
let db;

function setJsonToText(elId, json) { 
  gel(elId).innerText = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 3);
}
async function view() {
  // display db info
  setJsonToText('info', await db.info());
  // display total number or rows in the email index
  const result = await db.query('my_index/email', {
    include_docs: false,  
    limit: 0
  });
  setJsonToText('view', result);

}

// canned test documents
function getDocsToInstall() {
  return [{
      email: 'jerry@garcia.com',
    },
    {
      email: 'bob@weir.com',
    },
    {
      email: 'phil@lesh.com'
    },
    {
      email: 'wavy@gravy.com'
    },
    {
      email: 'samson@delilah.com'
    },
    {
      email: 'cosmic@charlie.com'
    },
    // design doc
    {
      _id: '_design/my_index',
      views: {
        email: {
          map: function(doc) {
            if (doc.email) emit(doc.email);
          }.toString()
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

// init example db instance
async function initDb() {
  db = new PouchDB('test', {
    adapter: 'memory'
  });

  await db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall());

};

(async() => {
  await initDb();
  await view();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb-7.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
<pre>Info</pre>
<pre id='info'></pre>
<div style='margin-top:2em'></div>
<pre>email view</pre>
<pre id='view'>
</pre>
```

Comment: Great thank you so much I’ll check it out later!!

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption:**

Assuming that following documents are  present in the Customers database:

```
[
{
  "_id": "93512c6c8585ab360dc7f535ff00bdfa",
  "_rev": "1-299289ee89275a8618cd9470733035f4",
  "name": "Tom",
  "email": "tom@domain.com"
 },
{
  "_id": "93512c6c8585ab360dc7f535ff00c930",
  "_rev": "1-a676883d6f1b5bce3b0a9ece92da6964",
  "name": "Tom Doe",
  "email": "tom@domain.com"
 },
{
  "_id": "93512c6c8585ab360dc7f535ff00edc0",
  "_rev": "1-09b5bf64cfe66af7e1134448e1a328c3",
  "name": "John",
  "email": "john@domain.com"
 },
{
  "_id": "93512c6c8585ab360dc7f535ff010988",
  "_rev": "1-88e347af11cfd1e40e63920fa5806fd2",
  "name": "Alan",
  "email": "alan@domain.com"
 }


]
```

If I understand your query correctly, then based on above data, You need below given result set.

```
{
"tom@domain.com": 2,
"alan@domain.com": 1,
"john@domain.com": 1
}
```

**Solution:**

In order to achieve above, Consider following design document containing a View which has Map and Reduce functions.

```
{
  "_id": "_design/Customers",
  "views": {
    "by-email": {
      
      "map": "function (doc) {
         if(doc.email){
              emit(doc.email, doc._id);
         }
       }",
      "reduce": "_count"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```

The above view function emits value of the key `email` of the document if the key exists in the document.

The reduce function `_count` is a built in reducer (provided by CouchDB) that does the counting logic.

**Executing View Query:**

In order to query this `view`, you need to: select the view function, mark reduce to be executed (as it is optional to run reduce) and set `1` as group level.

Here is  how you can do it through the UI:

[image: Executing map and reduce functions of a view]

**Result:**

Here is the result given by above query:
[![result of map reduce query

Hope this helped.
For more details about other reduce functions and group level, please refer CouchDB documentation.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GET /{db}`](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/common.html#get--db), which returns information about the specified database. This is a `JSON` object that contains the property `doc_count`.

> `doc_count` (number) – A count of the documents in the specified database.

With Angular for example, this could be done with the following method:

```
async countDocuments(database: string): Promise<number> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.url('GET', database), this.httpOptions).toPromise()
    .then(info => info['doc_count']);
}
```

Comment: Beware The db endpoint returns a count of *all* documents, including design documents